# Very strange behavior of OpenVPN between two sites

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, openvpn, bug

We've got a OpenVPN configured with layer2.
It is connected to a BGP router which announces a `/24` IPv4 and a `/29` IPv6. The purpose of the VPN is to redistribute IPv4 and IPv6.
However, recently I have been exhibiting very strange behavior.

When I launch OpenVPN, this is what I see:

[image: Total nonsense]

Here's the server configuration :

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tap
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server xx.xx.219.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
server-ipv6 xxxx:62c0::/64
tun-ipv6
push tun-ipv6
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "redirect-gateway ipv6"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_urnsnDa0CRP0bkx2.crt
key server_urnsnDa0CRP0bkx2.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

And, there is the configuration for a client :

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote 149.34.xxx.xxx 1194
dev tap
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_urnsnDa0CRP0bkx2 name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
[... following that there are only encryption key, so removed ...]
```

I'm totally lost.
I don't know what I misconfigured.
I'm wondering if this is a bug, and if so, how long it will take to resolve. If anyone has an idea. I'll take it.

Comment: Why does the server have `proto udp6` while the client connects with IPv4? Also, do the "nonsense" show up on a client or the server?